# Как сделать отложенный запуск смены индекса массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая разбивает массив чисел на массив из 5 цифр. Числовой массив содержит не одно число (которое является элементом массива уже под другим номером).

Как сделать так, чтобы по истечении минуты функция, которая разбивает число на цифры, обращалась к всё новому элементу массива (то есть к `arr1[1]`, `arr1[2]` и т.д.)?

Текущий код:

```
var arr1 = [27389, 23948, 59835, 39843, 17263];
var replaced;
var massiveReplaced = []
function ReplaceNum() {
    for (var temp = arr1[0], arr = []; temp;) {
        arr.unshift(temp % 10);
        temp = (temp - temp % 10) / 10
    };
    massiveReplaced =  arr
    console.log(massiveReplaced);
}
ReplaceNum();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте индекс в функцию `ReplaceNum(i);` и каждую минуту и устанавливайте таймаут, для автоматического вызова функции или смени индекса (тогда его надо где-то хранить).

```
setTimeout("ReplaceNum(1)", 1000); //через минуту вызвать функцию со следующим аргументом
```

Обратите внимание на кавычки - они нужны чтобы передать параметр. В кавычках может быть любой код.

Иначе можно хранить индекс где-нибудь. Например в свойстве функции, то есть так делаем:

```
function ReplaceNum() {
    for (var temp = arr1[ReplaceNum.index], arr = []; temp;) {
        arr.unshift(temp % 10);
        temp = (temp - temp % 10) / 10
    };
    massiveReplaced =  arr
    console.log(massiveReplaced);
    ReplaceNum.index++; // увеличили
}
ReplaceNum.index = 0; // начальное значение функции
ReplaceNum();
if(ReplaceNum.index < arr1.length) { // если еще есть элементы
    setTimeout(ReplaceNum, 1000); // поставили таймаут
}
```

Comment: Важно понимать, что этот подход можно использовать только, если точность выполнения не является критичной. Метод `setTimeout` не гарантирует точное время - особенно, в условиях недостатка процессорных ресурсов, или если вкладка находится "в фоне". Для наглядного примера написал фиддл http://jsfiddle.net/LfLmrya3/1/.

Answer (score 2):

Можно в функции обрабатывать только одно число, а следующий вызов функции для следующего числа делать спустя необходимую задержку с помощью `setTimeout`:

```js
var numbers = [27389, 23948, 59835, 39843, 17263];

function replaceNum(i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= numbers.length) {
        return;
    }
    var digits = (numbers[i] + "").split("");
    console.log(digits);
    setTimeout(function() { replaceNum(i + 1); }, 2000);
}
replaceNum(0);
```